# Select rows before null value in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How to subset or select rows before the occurrence of first null value in particular column for each group?

example

```
id sales
12   1
12   3
12    
12   5
15   4
15   6
15   9 
15   
15   1
```

and select only

```
df sales
12  1
12  3
15  4
15  6
15  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` with a custom function utilising `pd.Series.isnull`:

```
def index_filter(x):
    nulls = x.isnull()
    n = nulls[nulls].index[0] - 1
    return x.loc[:n]

res = df.groupby('id')['sales']\
        .apply(index_filter).astype(int)\
        .reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Alternatively, you can use a generator expression with `next`:

```
def index_filter(x):
    n = next((i for i, j in enumerate(x) if np.isnan(j)), len(x))
    return x.iloc[:n]
```

Result:

```
print(res)

   id  sales
0  12      1
1  12      3
2  15      4
3  15      6
4  15      9
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the nulls, groupby on ID, take the cumsum so that all rows before the first null have count 0 and those at and after the first have count 1 or more, and then select those.  IOW:

```
In [19]: df.loc[df["sales"].isnull().groupby(df["id"]).cumsum() < 1]
Out[19]: 
   id  sales
0  12    1.0
1  12    3.0
4  15    4.0
5  15    6.0
6  15    9.0
```

Comment: you're correct.  Thanks for the notifcation.  You've arrived at what my ahsnwer should have been. +1